# Do scopes affect the trajectory of your weapon's shots, or just make it easier to aim?

Tags: apex-legends

In Apex Legends there are a variety of different scopes you can pick up and attach to different weapons. They offering differing zoom levels and reticles, and some can highlight enemy players. A good scope can definitely make it easier to see and point at distance targets. However, even with a big scope attached, I still have a hard time landing shots on distant enemies.

[image]

This had me wondering whether scopes have any effect on the trajectory of your weapon's fire, or if they were only a visual tool to help the human player aim the shots. Do crosshairs have any effect on bloom, recoil, or other mechanical factors that make it harder to land shots at a distance, even if you get your crosshair pointed at the right spot?

Comment: I heard somewhere that aim is hitscan to a certain distance, after which point bullet drop kicks in. Don’t have a source for it though

Comment: Maybe the idea is that you're supposed to use both a scope and a stablizer mod if you want to actually hit things at these distances... I've had a few games now where my squad and another at shooting at each other across a canyon for a few minutes, and hardly grazing each other. :P

Comment: From my experience I say, that scopes help with the aim at larger distances and I believe that actual sniper scopes also act on the bullet drop. You will still need to calculate bullet speed into it to actual hit the target tho. Stabilizer reduce the recoil on each shot which makes it easier to shoot faster without having to readjust the height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is based on my own experience and might be completely off!*

From my experience I can say, that scopes do not influence the trajectory, but only make it easier to aim.

For example, take a sniper scope. Some of them have dots with the numbers 2, 3, 4 under the cross. If you now shoot at an enemy in a distance of up to 100 meter, you can see that there is no bullet drop. If the enemy is up to 200 meter away, you would need to aim with the dot with the number 2 next to it to actually hit the enemy. This means that for each 100 meter distance, the bullet drops by the distance between each dot in the scope.

Onto the close range scopes. I prefer the HOKV x1 scope as it has this red dot in the middle and no cluster around it. On short distance the bullets hit "exactly" where the red dot is (there is still weapon spread and other stuff making it not so exactly). Yet over greater distance the bullet still drops and the spread kicks in harder.

**So overall, are only a visual help for the players as its for great distances hard to even see the enemy without a scope. They don't influence the trajectory of the bullets in any way.**

The trajectory itself can't be influenced by any weapon modification, only the behavior of the weapon itself (recoil reduction through stabilizers).