# What exactly are the effects of Aiming Down Sights in apex legends?

Tags: apex-legends

Scoping = ADS bellow:

- Does the accuracy change (i.e. is not scoping in any way less accurate than the exact same aim/tracking with a scoping?)
- Does the spread change?
- Does the recoil change?"
- Are there other changes (except markings, zoom, thermal)?
- To which weapons do whatever changes (if any) apply?

If the answer to the above is no to everything, then are people seriously crippling movement just to get a mark on their screen!? I am asking because I generally hate scoping, except when totally necessary... but sometimes, I feel like I'm aiming great, but I'm not hitting anything without scoping, wondering if there are specific weapons which genuinely become inaccurate without scoping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do scopes affect the trajectory of your weapon's shots, or just make it easier to aim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/346189/do-scopes-affect-the-trajectory-of-your-weapons-shots-or-just-make-it-easier-t)

Comment: I am asking about scoping not scopes, I have update the post to make this a lot clearer.

Comment: @Purr I believe another common term for this would be Aim-Down Sight or ADS. might be worth editing in for people getting confused by the Dupe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scoping, more commonly known as Aiming Down Sights or ADS, gives you the following benefits:

- Significantly tighter spread on all weapons
- Zoom
- More Control for most weapons

However it has trade-offs, in the form of:

- Your mobility is lowered
- Less awareness as you are now focusing on a single direction
- Some Weapons, like SMGs without stabilizers/stocks become a bit wild

If you are using anything other than an SMG, you will hit more if you ADS. Even shotguns benefit greatly with ADS. The Peacekeeper with the choke hop-up, for example, tightens its spread so much it nearly becomes a rifle. Scout and Sniper Rifles pretty much require ADS to be effective. ARs and LMGs can go either way, but they are more effecting when ADS a majority of the time.

If you do not like to use the ADS mechanic, Apex probably isn't for you.

Comment: Well I'm no fan of ADS, but everything uses it nowadays, so I'll have to start using it, at least Apex actually has some movement skill in it and feels reasonably fast :)

Comment: P.S. I genuinely had no idea it was called aiming down sights or ADS... but something now makes sense... apex mentioned something about tightening Peacemakers spread with choke (i think) and it mentioned ADS, and I was wondering why are they using left right back to tighten spread?! Why doesn't it seem to make a difference?! Why am I still moving! Do I have to bind away from WASD to make this work? .... well now I know.

Comment: @Rapitor "*Your mobility is lowered*", you could precise the mobility is less decreased with a SMG (in compensation of its higher recoil).

Comment: @Purr the alternatives are often worse (IMHO), like using crouch or hold breath for more precise and steady shooting.

Comment: Well, I"m from an arena shooter background Quake/Quake3/UT/Nexuiz 2.52/Quake Live background, so not used to the idea of losing accuracy beyond the compromises between aim and movement, hitting and being hit :3 But I'm kinda getting into it, hard to work in scoping into the old reflexes, enjoying it though, fast enough, a little bit of movement skill as well :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume by scoping you mean ADSing, so right-clicking before shooting? Because scope, or no scope, the effects seem to be similar, at least as far as shotguns are concerned (I only tested shotguns).

In case of shotguns the pattern remains the same (triangle for mozambique, 5-star for peacekeeper, 8 shape for EVA-8, two parallel horizontal lines for mastiff), but in ADS is tighter, so you will hit more pellets when shooting at range and you should not ADS in close combat as you're risking missing with all your pellets.

I also distinctly remember Longbow being useless without ADS. It doesn't matter what scope you've got, if you can compensate you will still shoot your target, but if you try to hipfire, it will just shoot in random direction.

Comment: I wouldn't say shots fire in random directions, but are predictable. Pretty sure that hip firing any weapon is decently accurate and encouraged close range.

Comment: I was overexaggerating a little bit, but yes, almost any any weapon should be hip-fired close-range. The exception is Mozambique, as even close range you will not hit more than 1 pellet with hip-fire, so you actually need to ADS, unless the enemy player is literally in your face.

Comment: I think I'll turn on bullet marks next time i'm too drunk to play and get an idea of spread at different ranges with different weapons hip vs ads... didn"t think of this before asking question, because I haven"t played with bullet marks since 1996 :x